# Enable/Disable activation of a Form

Tags: c#, forms

I want to disable a `Form` from being activated. To do that I use this:

```cs
private const int WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x08000000;
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
   get
   {
      CreateParams createParams = base.CreateParams;
      createParams.ExStyle = WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;

      return createParams;
   }
}
```

This is fine for the main activity of my program because I can still click on the buttons and the `Form` won't activate. Whatever program is in the foreground stays there.

The problem is at the beginning of my program I need to input some text with the keyboard and for that the `Form` must be active or else the text will go to the program in the foreground.

I know where and when I want to enable/disable the `Form` ability to be activated, I just don't know how.

EDIT: And when it's not able to be active anymore I still want the buttons of the form to be clickable. With the code here it works like that. The real problem is at the beginning when I want to input some text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching even more around the Internet I found a simple one line solution:

`Activate();`

Didn't know this existed. Using the code in the question plus this on `Form_Load` I can have the program active at the beginning and stays that way until I change to another program. After that my program will never be active again.
Unless I put a button or something that calls Activate() again.

Answer (score 2):

The NoActivate flag isn't very well respected by Windows. You might have better luck rejecting the click message.

```
private const int WM_MOUSEACTIVATE = 0x0021, MA_NOACTIVATE = 0x0003;
    
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
  if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEACTIVATE) {
     m.Result = (IntPtr)MA_NOACTIVATE;
     return;
  }
  base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

that will let the click go through to the next window down. If you want to block the click entirely, use `MA_NOACTIVATEANDEAT = 0x0004` instead of `MA_NOACTIVATE`

If you don't need such strong protection, there is another flag you can override:

```
protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation => true;
```

Comment: That won't work. If you click in a button or something else the program will still be activated.
Using MA_NOACTIVATEANDEAT the clicks won't work. They need to always work.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't understand. Do you want to prevent clicks from activating the form, or are you trying to prevent some other event?

Comment: I want to prevent anything from activating the form but there's two catches:
1 - I still want to be able to click on the buttons of the form without activating it. I can do that with the code I'm currently using, the one I posted in the question. But there's a small problem: catch number 2.
2 - At the beginning of the program I want to input some text with the keyboard in a TextBox and for that the form must be active. Otherwise the text will go to whatever program is in the foreground at the time. After that it doesn't need to be active anymore.

Comment: Have a look at `https://github.com/i-e-b/WindowsJedi/tree/master/WindowsJedi/WinApis`; Calling something like `new Window(myForm.Handle).Focus()` when you need the text, then `new Window(myForm.Handle).NextVisibleBelow().Focus()` after you've got the textbox input should help -- this will drop your Form out of focus and bring the one behind it forward.

Comment: Too many lines of code plus didn't work. I found a solution that only has one line (see my answer).

Comment: Ah! I'd assumed if you were deep in Win32 you'd have known that one. Glad it's all working now!