# Disable program auto focus and bring to front desktop - winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, bringtofront

I'm developing program perform multiple tasks in the loop, use 3rd party libraries. But when it's done a job, it automatically appears in front of screen, made me lose focus. How to disable auto appear? I've tried:

```
private void FrmMain_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendToBack();
}
```

But it was only after the program appear, bring it back to the rear. I want to prevent it bring to front from the firt. Please help me!

Comment: Is it something in the third-party libraries that causes your form to bring to front? To my best understanding, if you run a form, start some process, minimize the form or switch to another application, it should stay minimized or out of view. Are these libraries WinForms controls, or have WinForms controls?

Comment: I'm using ChromiumWebBrowser for winforms. Even I minimized my progam and switched to another program, it still make lose focus...

Comment: Crazy idea, but what if you made your form an MDI Child of another form? It should prevent the parent form from coming up, I think

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894343/enable-disable-activation-of-a-form

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037250/how-do-i-create-an-unfocusable-form-in-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750517/notification-window-preventing-the-window-from-ever-getting-focus

Comment: @mohsen all don't work for me :(